# SQL Server Update statement for variable table name, column names and values

Tags: sql-server

I wrote the following stored procedure that receives values from my code and runs it in a loop based on table column count, all the values are stored and passed correctly in the code which leads me to believe the problem is with my stored procedure.

This is my current error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UPDATE DBName..TableName SET [Name] = Test WHERE [pkJMParamsID = 'to data type int'

I can fix this by changing `@colIDValue` to a `varchar`, which it shouldn't be because the pk is an int, but if I do this the next error I get is that 'Test Update' is not a valid column name even tough in my syntax it's at the value position, so I must be doing something very wrong.

Note: The values assigned to the parameters are just for testing.
Please tell me if any more information is required.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName]
    @tableName VARHAR(255) = 'a table Name',
    @colName VARCHAR(255) = 'Name',
    @colValue VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Test',
    @colID VARCHAR(255) = 'pkJMParamsID',
    @colIDValue INT = 1
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(MAX) 

    SET @str = N'UPDATE DBName..' + @tableName + ' SET ' +quotename(@colName)+ ' = ' +@colValue+ ' WHERE ' +quotename(@colID)+ ' = ' +@colIDValue+ '';

    EXEC (@str)

    SELECT 1 AS 'Result','' as 'Error'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 0 AS 'Result',
            ERROR_MESSAGE() as 'Error'
END CATCH

--EXEC [dbo].[spName]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@colValue` is varchar so it's should be between quotes

```
SET @str = N'UPDATE DBName..' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET ' +quotename(@colName)+ ' = ''' +@colValue+ ''' WHERE ' +quotename(@colID)+ ' = ' +@colIDValue+ '';
```

Also `quotename()` `@tableName`

You should take a look to `sp_executeSQL` instead of `exec()`

Comment: Thanks alot! This resolves my problem if I change colIDValue INT = 1 to colIDValue VARCHAR(255) = 1 but colIDValue should be int because it's the parameter for my primary key and was created as int, I can as stated above make it work with it being a varchar but I find it strange that I can't use it as an int parameter, is there some reason why ?

Comment: You are adding it to a varchar so it's should be a varchar. You can't add numbers to a string. take a look to sp_executesql to see how to pass parameters.

Comment: I never casted the int to varchar, thanks alot for your help !

Comment: Just as I saw the problem haha